# Center of a set

Tags: normed-spaces

Here are the definitions of a radius and center. Let $A\subset G$

$r(A)= \inf _{g \in G}  \sup _{g_{1} \in A}  ||g- g_{1}||$

If for some $g* \in G$ is $r(A)= \sup _{g_{1} \in A} ||g*- g_{1}||$, then $g*$ is a center of $A$.

So I am looking for a set in a normed space which does not have a center. But most importantly I am wondering how can I tell if a set does not have a center.  By contradiction I should show that $r(A)\not= \sup _{g_{1} \in A} ||g*- g_{1}||$. In order to do that I would have to know $r(A)$, but how can I know a radius without knowing the center.

Comment: Obviously, the center of a ball is its center in the usual sense. I would try with two disjoint balls..

Comment: I think two disjoint balls also will have a center, which would be in the middle of the line connecting centers of the balls.

Comment: Ah, yes, I thought the center should be a point in the set, but I see now that's not required.

Comment: Look up Chebyshev centre. You can also define this in terms of the smallest ball enclosing the set. An obvious requirement is that the set be bounded.

Comment: If $G$ is not complete, there is a rather simple construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it: For $G$ not complete:

Let $G=\mathbb{Q}$ and $A:=[\sqrt{2}-1,\sqrt{2}+1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$.

Then there is no center in $G$, because if there was, then it would have to be $\sqrt{2}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$